# Multiple Arrays Output Results in Blank Lines

Tags: arrays, powershell, console, output

I am trying to output the results of multiple arrays (3) to the same output (console).  Code is roughly like this:

```
$array1
foreach ($item in $array1)
{
  $array2 = get list of services for $item
  $array2 = get list of schedtasks for $item
  if ($array2)
  {
    write-host "array2 data"
    $array2
  }
  if ($array3)
  {
    write-host "array3 data"
    $array3
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that once the first array outputs, the console seem to attach itself to that array's column heading and only displays data for the other arrays if they also have a column heading that matches the first array's column heading.  It still outputs a blank line for each row that doesn't match the heading, indicating that the other arrays are populated.

I verified this by creating and outputting a custom array beforehand with all the same column headings as all the other arrays combined.  Now I get all my data, but in 4 columns that line up with the original custom array.

I'm using Powershell ISE and it does this in both Server 2008 R2 with Powershell 2 and Server 2012 R2 with Powershell 4, which leads me to believe this is expected behavior and I'm not understanding something.

Any ideas what's going on and how I can get the array data output to be handled independently of the previous array's output?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code does not say enough, you removed too much of the logic. Can you edit your post to show what the input arrays look like and what you expect on our screen as result ?

Comment: piping to out-host seems to do the trick.  Thanks PetSerAl!  If you want to add that as an answer, I'll mark this as answered.

sodawillow, array1 contains a list of computer names, single column.  array2 is a list of scheduled tasks and account rans as, and array3 is a list of service names and account ran as.  I'm just populating the arrays using the various commands to get that kind of info: get-adcomputer, gwmi, and schtasks.exe.  It seems simple, because that's pretty much it.  Hope that helps.

Comment: `$array1 | Out-Host` ? :-p but it seems to me your loop echoes `$array2` and `$array3` entirely for each value of `$array1`, the use of which I don't understand :)

Comment: I see now.  No, you're right.  I updated the code section for clarity.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known PowerShell problem, that it is not very good in formatting objects with different set of properties:

```
$a = [PSCustomObject]@{a=1; b=2}
$b = [PSCustomObject]@{b=2; c=3}
$a, $b # table with properties a and b  not c
$b, $a # table with properties b and c  not a
```

To format arrays independently from each other, you can pass each array to separate call of `Out-Host` cmdlet instead of writing arrays to output:

```
$array2 | Out-Host
$array3 | Out-Host
```